# Showing $\partial \partial S= \partial S$ for open sets $S$ in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a Metric Space and $S \subset X$ an Open set

Show that $\partial \partial S = \partial S$

I was wondering if my reasoning is right.

We know $\partial S = Int \; \partial S  \cup \partial \partial S$

So it suffices to show that $Int \; \partial S = \emptyset$

Since $cl(S) = Int(S) \cup \partial S \implies cl(S) = S \cup \partial S$

We have $\partial S =cl(S) \cap cl(S^c) \implies \partial S = (S \cup \partial S) \cap S^c \implies \partial S = \partial S \cap S^c \implies \partial S \subset S^c$

Hence if $x \in Int  \; \partial S \; \exists \; \epsilon >0\implies D(x, \epsilon) 
\subset \partial S \subset S^c$

But Then $D(x,\epsilon) \cap S = \emptyset$ and so $x \notin \partial S$ which is a contradiction

Does this seem right?

Comment: Everything is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. It holds in every topological space that the boundary of an open set, and thus also the boundary of a closed set has empty interior, and since it is closed, we have $\partial\partial S = \partial S$.